# How to prove that the triangular numbers follow the pattern of being odd, odd, even, even, odd, odd...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

How can I prove that the triangular numbers are odd, odd, even, even in pattern.
The first 8 triangular numbers being 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36.

The nth triangular number is $T_n = n(n+1)/2$

My first thought is to assume $T_n$ and $T_{n+1}$ are odd and then show that the next two triangular numbers are even and the next too odd then using induction.

I could also try by assuming $T_n$ and $T_{n+1}$ are odd and then the next two even, followed by assuming $T_n$ and $T_{n+1}$ are even and showing the next two are odd.

I am wondering if there is a shorter approach.

Comment: $T_{n+4} = T_n + (n+1) + (n+2) + (n+3) +(n+4) = T_n + 4n + 10 \equiv T_n \bmod 2$

Comment: Adding an even number does not change the parity, while adding an odd number does change the parity (from odd to even or vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof by recurrence is possible, as indicated in a comment. But actually a direct proof is as simple. There are $4$ cases:

- $n = 0 \pmod 4$: then $n/2$ is even so $T_n$ is even.
- $n = 1 \pmod 4$: then $n+1 = 2 \pmod 4$, so both $n$ and $(n+1)/2$ are odd, so $T_n$ is odd.
- $n = 2 \pmod 4$: then both $n/2$ and $n+1$ are odd, so $T_n$ is odd.
- $n = 3 \pmod 4$: then $n+1 = 0 \pmod 4$, so $(n+1)/2$ is even, and $T_n$ is even.

It also shows well why the situation is the same for $n = 0 \pmod 4$ and $n = 3 \pmod 4$, and the same for $n = 1 \pmod 4$ and $n = 2 \pmod 4$.

Comment: **Easier** to user $\,T_{n+2}\,$ has opposite parity to $\,T_n,\,$ e.g. see may answer. $\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $ $ incrementing the index by $\:\!2\:\!$ toggles *parity*, i.e. $\!\bmod 2\!:\  T_{n+2} \equiv T_n+1\,$ hence $\,T_1,T_2\equiv 1,1\Rightarrow T_3,T_4\equiv 0,0.\,$ This initial sequence $\equiv 1,1,0,0\,$ is a period that  cycles forever by  $\,T_{n+\color{c00}4}\equiv \underbrace{T_{n+2}}_{\large T_n+1}\!+1\equiv T_n.\ $ More generally see below.

---

**Theorem** $ $ If the sequence $\,a_k\,$ satisfies $\,a_{k+2} = f(a_k)\,$ where $f$ has period $\,\color{#c00}2,\,$ i.e. $\,f^2(x) = x,\,$ then the sequence $\,a_k\,$ has period $\:\!4=2\cdot\color{#c00}2,\,$ infinitely cycling the values $\,a_1,a_2,f(a_1),f(a_2)$.

**Proof** $ $ By hypothesis $\,a_3=f(a_1),\,a_4 = f(a_2),\,$ and $\,a_{n+4} = f(a_{n+2}) = f^2(a_n) = a_n,\,$ so the claim follows by an obvious induction.

Comment: Note that the order (*minimal* period) may be $< 4$, e.g. $\,2\,$  if $\,f(a_i)=a_i\,$ 
 and $\,a_1\neq a_2\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach: Try using the fact that when you add an even number to a total, the new total has the same parity (odd or even) as the previous total; but when you add an odd number to a total the new total has the opposite parity as the previous total.

Try to apply this to the running sum $1 + 2 + 3 + ...$ that gives you the successive triangular numbers as you go along.